# How to get /etc/ directory

Tags: c, glib

I have function:

```
gint isfileexists(gchar *filename) 
{
struct stat buffer; 
gint i = stat(filename, &buffer);
if (i == 0) {
   return 1;
}
return 0;
}
```

and if I call them:

```
isfileexists("/etc/myfile")
```

it search "myfile" in "/home/user/etc/myfile". How to do this well?

Comment: What is `gint`, `gchar`? And are you sure that's how you're calling it, and that's what it's doing?

Comment: gint and gchar is from glib: https://developer.gnome.org/glib/

Comment: You'll  have to use `const char *home = getenv("HOME");` to find the value of `$HOME` and then prepend that to the file name you're given.  Otherwise, it will look in the system's `/etc` directory for `myfile` and probably won't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should only look for `/home/USER/etc/myfile` if:

- you leave off the leading `/` when calling `isfileexists`; and
- that directory `/home/USER` is your current working directory.

In other words, if the argument is a *relative* path name.

Since you *have* the leading `/`, it will be an absolute path name and should access `/etc/myfile`.

If I've misunderstood and you actually *want* the one in your home directory, you can use `getenv("HOME")` to get your home directory and then append `/etc/myfile` with `strcat`. That will also work regardless of your current working directory.

Comment: Don't assume your home directory is `/home/username`.